# Do you need a mac to work on websites originally built with Iweb

Tags: iweb

Do you need a Mac to work on websites originally built with Iweb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you want to edit it.  If you want to keep the same interface, yes; I could be wrong here, but it does output HTML, so you can just edit the HTML in any editor.

Answer (score 0):

Technically?  No, you don't, the code exists there for you to edit.  Note that Iweb does use some javascript libraries, but theres nothing thats encoded or obfuscated in the acutal web pages.

Just note that if you change the acutal code, then go back to Iweb, Iweb will likely overwrite your changes.